# jQuery Validation Plugin: password field not being validated

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in a jQuery Mobile project. I've a simple login form where I need to ensure that both user name and password fields are not empty. Here´s the HTML:

```
            <form id="my_form">
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User" class="required" />
                <input type="password" id="userpsw" placeholder="Password" class="required" />
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
```

And here's the code:

```
             $(document).on("pageinit", function(){        
                $("#my_form").validate({
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                      alert("All fields ok!");
                    }
                 });
            });
```

The problem is that only the user name field is being validated. With only the user name filled, when I press the submit button, the "All fields ok" dialog is shown. I've tested this in Chrome and Firefox, and the result is the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Does this plugin work with passwords?

---

UPDATE: I've changed the password input type to "text", and it keeps failing.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your working code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP the working code is the same I've posted above, but adding the `name` attribute to the first two inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to set a name attribute on your input elements?

The jQuery validation plugin requires every `<input />` element to have a valid name attribute set. From the documentation:

`The name attribute is required for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it.`

[Markup recommendations](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Markup_recommendations)

Comment: Amazing. Fastest solution ever. +1

Comment: Bjorn, you should turn this most minimal answer into something worthy of many up-votes.  Simply explain how the jQuery Validate plugin requires that all `input` elements have a `name` attribute and link to the documentation.

Comment: @Sparky, thanks for the tip. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `class="required"` with **`required`** only.

Test: [Form](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKzf/)

Comment: Weird, it's a HTML5 attribute for forms.

Comment: According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=required), html5 validation is not supported in several mobile platforms, that's why I'm using jQuery.validate.

Comment: Thanks, i remember it was working. But it seems that I am ought to validate my search form.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: The JQ validation.js Didnt work with JQM 'Dialog' but worked on a normal page. I used a simple JS validation without JQ validation.js